# Combining gantt chart and line chart using highchart

Tags: highcharts

Actually i want to merge highchart line series and ganttchart together in same chart. please help me with thsi.

i tred to add a spline series to the gantt but this did not work.

Answer (score 2):

To have access to every basic series, you need to use `Highcharts` source code and add `Gantt` as a module:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/gantt.js"></script>
```

Now it is possible to use `line` series in `ganttChart`:

```
series: [..., {
    data: [{
        y: 1,
        start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 17)
    }, {
        y: 1,
        start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 24)
    }, {
        y: 2,
        start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 27)
    }],
    type: 'line'
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xm7daL3b/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/gantt/getting-started-gantt

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you!!